# Azure SQL DB: Check if "Allow azure services to access server" is enabled after DB created

Tags: sql, azure, ssis

In working towards setting up ADF for SSIS access to my Azure DB, I need to check that the "Allow azure services to access server" is enabled. The database has however already been created and I cannot find any obvious links in Azure portal as to where I can find this setting now.

As example of what I'm looking for. refer https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2018/01/azure-ssis-how-to-setup-deploy-execute-schedule-packages/

Comment: include details on what you are looking here in SO . instead of pointing to external links. that would be easy to understand your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right, you could follow my steps to find the setting.

1.open your Azure Sql Database on azure portal,then go to **Set server firewall**.

[image]

2.check the **Allow access to Azure services** setting.

[image]